# Start Dicom Viewer Application on Client Side

Tags: php, jquery-plugins, html5-canvas, dicom

i am developing a patient dicom image maintain application using php(Codeigniter).
i have a trouble with dicom viewer.

i am using radiant dicom viewer. So how can i launch Dicom viewer with patient images on client side?
*(Or any possible ways to view images with all these facilities)*

Comment: It would be interesting to know which approach you selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 general approaches to this: If the viewer supports WADO (Web-Access to DICOM objects), you can probably just invoke the viewer with identifying. But Radiant does not support WADO currently.

However, Radiant supports some [command line options](http://www.radiantviewer.com/dicom-viewer-manual/command-line_arguments.htm) which might be helpful:

So you have 2 approaches to implement the second general approach:

1. Obtain the identifying information for the images from the Webserver and pass them to the Radiant Viewer with a custom protocol handler as described by John.
2. Downnload the images with your own custom protocol handler and pass them to the Radiant viewer.

The first approach will require the radiant viewer to be pre-configured as a DICOM node in the PACS and it will impose limitations on how the images can be bundled because you have to convert the "whatever the user clicked on" to a single identifier. The Radiant documentation reads as if it just supports the patient level which is probably not want you want. It is unclear to me where the viewer will download the images from with the -pstv option.

The second one (Radiant option -d, hopefully it will not only scan but load the images) will cause more effort for your custom protocol handler. But you are in full control over the set of images which will be loaded by the viewer

I would recommend to you to play with the different options of Radiant and how they behave in detail before selecting the one or the other approach

HTH

kritzel_sw

Answer (score 1):

You just need to define a custom URL protocol. There are several examples around;

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/332206/Custom-URL-Protocol-for-Invoking-Application

Comment: I disagree, it is not that easy because typically DICOM images are coming in large series. It does not make sense to start the viewer for each single image

Comment: thanks i mixed up both ideas and it works. really thanks both of you.